# Leaflet draws location pins, but not path; "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')"

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, nuxt3

I'm trying to use the latest stable version of Leaflet (1.9.4) with OpenStreetMap and Nuxt3 to show the route between two given locations, but it only shows the pins. I have confirmed that the coordinates are formatted correctly, and that the leaflet-router object is initialized, so I'm not sure why I'm getting an 'undefined' error.

```js
<template>
  <div class="leaflet-window">
    <l-map ref="map" :zoom="13" :center="[47.60, -122.30]" :useGlobalLeaflet="false" @ready="setMap">
      <l-tile-layer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"></l-tile-layer>
      <l-geo-json :geojson="geojson" :options="geojsonOptions" />
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
async setupRouting() {

  const L = await import('leaflet');
  await import('leaflet-routing-machine');
  await import('leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css');

  if (this.originCoords.length > 0 && this.destinationCoords.length > 0) {
    if (this.routingControl) {
      this.map.removeControl(this.routingControl);
    }

    // Here, I log the values of the inputted coordinates to make sure they're formatted correctly
    const orgn = L.latLng(this.originCoords[0], this.originCoords[1]);
    const dest = L.latLng(this.destinationCoords[0], this.destinationCoords[1]);
    console.log("orgn: " + orgn); // LatLng(47.603832, -122.330062)
    console.log("dest: " + dest); // LatLng(47.669414, -122.123877)

    console.log(this.map); // This appears to be fully initialized

    this.routingControl = L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [
        L.latLng(this.originCoords[0], this.originCoords[1]),
        L.latLng(this.destinationCoords[0], this.destinationCoords[1])
      ],
      routeWhileDragging: false,
      showAlternatives: false,
      fitSelectedRoutes: true,
      show: false
    }).addTo(this.map);

    console.log(this.routingControl); // So does this
  } else {
    console.log("Origin and destination must be defined to set up routing.");
  }
}
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRIyq.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBa9Y.png)

The leaflet-router should show the route between the two locations I provided.  Instead, only the pins are drawn, and there is no route.